# how to initialize a non copyable object data member

Tags: c++, object-initializers

I want to use an already implemented abstract class (which can be seen as "A" in my simple provided code) in my code. 
I defined class "B" to implement those pure virtual methods. The fact, here, is that the objects of this class cannot be copyable then, as the operator= is deleted in abstract class. 
I have class "Z" which has a data member of "B" class object. I want to initialize the object as you see in the code. But as it is a non-copyable one, for sure it show errors like   *use of deleted function ‘NS::B::B(NS::B&&)’*  . I don't know how should I have this object as data member and also initialize it with proper data. 
The simple version of the code is as follow:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

namespace NS {
class A //abstract class
{
public:
    A() = default;
    A& operator=(const A& other) = delete;
    A(const A& other) = delete;
};
}

namespace NS {
class B : public A
{
public:
    B(int p);
};
}

namespace SI {
class Z
{
public:
    Z(int p, std::string name);
private:
    NS::B obj3;
};
typedef std::shared_ptr<SI::Z> ZPtr;
}

SI::Z::Z(int p, std::string name) : obj3(p)
{}

namespace SI {
class Y
{
public:
    Y(int p);
private:
    SI::ZPtr obj2;
};
}

SI::Y::Y(int p) : obj2(std::make_shared<SI::Z>(SI::Z(p,"hi")))
{}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: probably just missing includes, but I get loads of errros that are unrelated to your question: https://wandbox.org/permlink/umVfs33yaFnIaLON

Comment: you know that `class A : B` is private inheritance, right? for inheriting the interface private inheritance makes not much sense...

Comment: user463035818  Sorry, I forgot to copy the includes. now I edited that. and also it should be copiled with c++11. I also corrected public inheritance, although it isnot affected on the problem.

Comment: You CAN initialize your object. You CAN'T use std::make_shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the above compile:

Add the headers:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
```

You also need to be able to construct the `A` so you need to make the constructors public:

```
class A //abstract class
{
    public:               // Added this:
         A() = default;
    .....
};
```

Your main issue is here in making the shared object.

```
 obj2(std::make_shared<SI::Z>(SI::Z(p,"hi")))
```

You don't need to constructed the `SI::Z` object here (as it is not copyable this is an issue). What you want to do is pass the arguments that will be used to create the `SI::Z` object. Then `std::make_shared()` will call new and forward these parameters to the constructor.

```
 obj2(std::make_shared<SI::Z>(p, "hi"))     // Notice the diff?
```